# How to check / reload automaticaly rss feed with feedparser?

Tags: python, rss, reload, feed, feedparser

I started to get interested in python and feedparser. I would like to know how to get the new entries of an rss automatically without having to restart the script to get the new entries.

When there is an update, it retrieves the information I ask it for the rest of my script.

```py
import time
import feedparser

rss = "https://example.com"

feed = feedparser.parse(rss)
url_base = (feed.entries[0]['link'])
first_title = (feed.entries[0]['title'])

while 1 :
    feed = feedparser.parse(rss)  
    url_check = (feed.entries[0]['link'])
    sleep(randint(200, 250))

    if url_check != url_base :
        feed = feedparser.parse(rss)
        title = (feed.entries[0]['title'])
        description = (feed.entries[0]['description'])
        link = (feed.entries[0]['link'])
        url_base = url_check
        [...]
```

I've also thought about that, but I don't know if it's viable.

```py
import time
import feedparser

rss = "https://example.com"
rss_check = False

while rss_check is False:
    feed = feedparser.parse(rss)  
    title = (feed.entries[0]['title'])
    link = (feed.entries[0]['link'])
    description = (feed.entries[0]['description'])
    [...]
```